# How to make the element content flow along with maintaining min-width

Tags: javascript, html, css

We can make an element wrap into next line by making the display : inline.
for eg as shown in image below

[image: Each element is a span with min-width 20%]

How can we make the content wrap into line along with maintaining the min-width.
We also need the other elements to start where previous element ends.
[image: Min-Width needs to be 20%]

The css used is :

```
 span.block {
                display:inline;
                width:auto;
                min-width:20%;
                border:1px solid #cfcfcf;
                line-height:25px;
                margin:3px;
                background-color:#3f3f3f;
                color:#f1f1f1;
                border-radius:3px;
                padding-right:20px;
}
```

Here is the fiddler http://jsfiddle.net/yCvhB/57/

Comment: Wouldn't it look silly if there's an empty black bar alone on the next line if the text fits on the previous line but the entire 500px doesn't?

Comment: Have given 500 px is just an example. consider it to be 30px or in %.

Comment: Is this what you need? http://jsfiddle.net/yCvhB/55/show/ Changed `display:inline;` to `display:inline-block;`

Comment: making inline-block would not allow next item content to start from same line as that of end of previous element

Comment: Next item will start at the end of the previous element only if there's at least 500px empty space left of the remaining width, to satisfy `min-width:500;` that is your requirement. What do you exactly want from `min-width:500px`?

Comment: @Arbel I assume he wants it to look exactly like the images in the question, except that if the text is narrower than 500px there should be enough whitespace at the end so that the element will be 500px wide.

Comment: (It doesn't make any difference if it's percentages or pixels.)

Comment: @Padmalochan I don't think this is possible in CSS alone. Is using JavaScript ok?

Comment: Consider min-width:20%. But its not workable.

Comment: yes no problem in using Javascript

Comment: Here's `display:inline-block;` with `min-width:50px;` http://jsfiddle.net/yCvhB/58/show/ I think further assumption will not work unless you are sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Arbel i just need the min-width to be working in along with the text wrapping up to next line within the container as shown in http://jsfiddle.net/yCvhB/57/

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could think of is to add as many spaces as it takes to make the element long enough.

```
var minWidth = 300;

var blocks = document.getElementsByClassName( 'block' );
var numOfBlocks = blocks.length;

for( var i = 0; i < numOfBlocks; ++i ) {
    var block = blocks[ i ];

    // make text not wrap temporarily so that the width is
    // calculated correctly
    block.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap';

    while( block.offsetWidth < minWidth ) {
        block.innerHTML += ' &nbsp;';
    }

    // reset whitespace style    
    block.style.whiteSpace = 'normal';
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yCvhB/61/

Comment: This works cool for px but how to make it work when we give min-width in percentage

Comment: You have to calculate the pixel value of the percentage (reference element's width times the percentage). Unfortunately there's no easy way to make it work if the user resizes the browser window after the page has loaded.